# Trying to debug Adjacent JSX elements error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting a `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag` error.

How do you debug JSX and where are the errors?

```
var React  = require('react');

var Home = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
    <div>
       <header>
         <div className="container">
             <div className="row">
                 <div className="col-md-12">
                      <h1>Hello World</h1>
                      <p className="lead">This is an Awesome App Landing Page</p>

                      <div className="carousel-iphone">
                        <div id="carousel-example-generic" className="carousel slide">

                        <ol className="carousel-indicators">
                          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
                          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>

                        <div className="carousel-inner">
                          <div className="item active">
                            <img src="img/screenshots/app-1.png" alt="App Screen 1"></img>
                          </div>
                          <div className="item">
                            <img src="img/screenshots/app-2.png" alt="App Screen 2" ></img>
                          </div>
                          <div className="item">
                            <img src="img/screenshots/app-3.png" alt="App Screen 3" ></img>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>    
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>

    <div>
        <section className="purchase">
          <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                     <h1>Everything's easily customizable.</h1>
                            <p className="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                            <button type="button" className="app-store"></button>   
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </section>
    </div>

     <div>
          <section className="payoff">
            <div className="container">
                  <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-md-12">
                          <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</h1>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>      
          </section>
     </div>


        <div>
              <section className="detail">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <div id="carousel-example-generic-2" className="carousel slide">

                              <div className="carousel-inner">
                                <div className="item active">
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-6">
                                            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h1>
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                            <div className="app-screenshot">
                                                <img src="img/screenshots/app-1.png" className="img-responsive" alt="App Screen 1">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="item">
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-6">
                                            <h1>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</h1>
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                            <div className="app-screenshot">
                                                <img src="img/screenshots/app-2.png" className="img-responsive" alt="App Screen 2">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="item">
                                  <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-6">
                                        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h1>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                        <div className="app-screenshot">
                                            <img src="img/screenshots/app-3.png" className="img-responsive" alt="App Screen 3">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <ol className="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-2" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                              </ol>     
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>


        <div>     
              <section className="features">
                  <div className="container">
                      <div className="row">

                          <div className="col-md-4">
                              <div className="circle"><i className="icon-bookmark"></i></div>
                              <h2>Quick &amp; Easy Setup</h2>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                          </div>

                          <div className="col-md-4">
                              <div className="circle"><i className="icon-keypad"></i></div>
                              <h2>Parallax Scrolling</h2>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                          </div>

                          <div className="col-md-4">
                              <div className="circle"><i className="icon-like"></i></div>
                              <h2>Responsive Design</h2>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                          </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </section>
         </div>


         <div>
              <section className="social">
                <div className="container">
                      <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-md-12">
                            <h2>Connect with us</h2>
                            <a className="icon-facebook"></a>
                            <a className="icon-twitter"></a>
                            <a className="icon-google"></a>
                            <a className="icon-instagram"></a>
                            <a className="icon-pinterest"></a>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>      
              </section>
         </div>


         <div>
              <section className="get-it">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <h1>Avaialable now on the App Store</h1>
                            <p className="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                            <button type="button" className="app-store"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <hr />
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#link-here">Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#link-here">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#link-here">Press</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#link-here">Support</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#link-here">Developers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#link-here">Privacy</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </section>
         </div>
    );
    }
});

module.exports = Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that error is that you have several `div`'s that are siblings to one another. The way to fix this is to enclose all the `div`'s you have in your code by another enclosing tag (in your case it seems like another `div` tag should do the trick.

I added `<div id="closingDiv">`. I would give this code a try:

```
var React  = require('react');

var Home = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
    <div id="closingDiv">
      <div>
         <header>
           <div className="container">
               <div className="row">
                   <div className="col-md-12">
                        <h1>Hello World</h1>
                        <p className="lead">This is an Awesome App Landing Page</p>

                        <div className="carousel-iphone">
                          <div id="carousel-example-generic" className="carousel slide">

                          <ol className="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                          </ol>

                          <div className="carousel-inner">
                            <div className="item active">
                              <img src="img/screenshots/app-1.png" alt="App Screen 1"></img>
                            </div>
                            <div className="item">
                              <img src="img/screenshots/app-2.png" alt="App Screen 2" ></img>
                            </div>
                            <div className="item">
                              <img src="img/screenshots/app-3.png" alt="App Screen 3" ></img>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>    
              </div>    
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>

      <div>
          <section className="purchase">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                       <h1>Everything\'s easily customizable.</h1>
                              <p className="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                              <button type="button" className="app-store"></button>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </section>
      </div>

       <div>
            <section className="payoff">
              <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </section>
       </div>


          <div>
                <section className="detail">
                  <div className="container">
                      <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-md-12">
                              <div id="carousel-example-generic-2" className="carousel slide">

                                <div className="carousel-inner">
                                  <div className="item active">
                                      <div className="row">
                                          <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-6">
                                              <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h1>
                                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                                          </div>
                                          <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                              <div className="app-screenshot">
                                                  <img src="img/screenshots/app-1.png" className="img-responsive" alt="App Screen 1">
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div className="item">
                                      <div className="row">
                                          <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-6">
                                              <h1>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</h1>
                                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                                          </div>
                                          <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                              <div className="app-screenshot">
                                                  <img src="img/screenshots/app-2.png" className="img-responsive" alt="App Screen 2">
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div className="item">
                                    <div className="row">
                                      <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-6">
                                          <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h1>
                                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                          <div className="app-screenshot">
                                              <img src="img/screenshots/app-3.png" className="img-responsive" alt="App Screen 3">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                                <ol className="carousel-indicators">
                                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-2" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
                                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                </ol>     
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </section>
          </div>


          <div>     
                <section className="features">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">

                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <div className="circle"><i className="icon-bookmark"></i></div>
                                <h2>Quick &amp; Easy Setup</h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <div className="circle"><i className="icon-keypad"></i></div>
                                <h2>Parallax Scrolling</h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <div className="circle"><i className="icon-like"></i></div>
                                <h2>Responsive Design</h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
           </div>


           <div>
                <section className="social">
                  <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                              <h2>Connect with us</h2>
                              <a className="icon-facebook"></a>
                              <a className="icon-twitter"></a>
                              <a className="icon-google"></a>
                              <a className="icon-instagram"></a>
                              <a className="icon-pinterest"></a>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </section>
           </div>


           <div>
                <section className="get-it">
                  <div className="container">
                      <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-md-12">
                              <h1>Avaialable now on the App Store</h1>
                              <p className="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                              <button type="button" className="app-store"></button>
                          </div>
                          <div className="col-md-12">
                              <hr />
                              <ul>
                                  <li><a href="#link-here">Contact</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#link-here">Twitter</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#link-here">Press</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#link-here">Support</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#link-here">Developers</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#link-here">Privacy</a></li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
           </div>
         </div>
    );
    }
});

module.exports = Home;
```